# Revoking Celery task causes Heroku dyno worker timeout

Tags: django, heroku, celery

My Django API app has a view class that defines a post and a patch method. The post method creates a reservation resource with a user-defined expiration time and creates a Celery task which changes said resource once the user-defined expiration time has expired. The patch method gives the user the ability to update the expiration time. Changing the expiration time also requires changing the Celery task. In my patch method, I use `app.control.revoke(task_id=task_id, terminate=True, signal="SIGKILL")` to revoke the existing task, followed by creating a new task with the amended expiration time.

All of this works just fine in my local Docker setup. But once I deploy to Heroku the Celery worker appears to be terminated after the execution of the above `app.control.revoke(...)` causes a request timeout with an H12 error code.

```
2021-11-21T16:39:35.509103+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=PATCH path="/update-reservation-unauth/30/emailh@email.com/" host=secure-my-spot-api.herokuapp.com request_id=e0a304f8-3901-4ca1-a5eb-ba3dc06df999 fwd="108.21.217.120" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-11-21T16:39:35.835796+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-11-21 16:39:35 +0000] [3] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:5)
2021-11-21T16:39:35.836627+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-11-21 16:39:35 +0000] [5] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 5)
```

I would like to emphasise that the timeout cannot possibly be caused by calculation complexity as the Celery task only changes a boolean field on the reservation resource.

For reference, the Celery service in my docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
worker:
  container_name: celery
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  command: celery -A secure_my_spot.celeryconf worker --loglevel=INFO
  depends_on:
    - db
    - broker
    - redis
  restart: always
```

I have looked everywhere for a solution but have not found anything that helps and I am drawing a blank as to what could possibly cause this issue with the deployed Heroku app whilst the local development containers work just fine.